# Orchard 1.8 Workflow sends 2 email notifications

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I've set up a workflow in Orchard CMS 1.8 to email the administrator when a new comment is created. It sends 2 notifications for some reason. I use the {Content.CommentAuthor} and {Content.CommentMessage} variables in the Workflow and one of the emails they are empty. Why would Orchard be sending 2 notifications?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the "Send notification email" turned on in Site settings (Comments section). If so, Comments module will automatically send an e-mail to the author, apart from the second e-mail sent via workflow.

Comment: I don't have a "Send notification email" setting. Do I have to have a specific module enabled to see it?